# Hooking to a C++ DLL event form C#

Tags: c#, c++, events, dll

I want to hook a C# method to a C++ event written in the C++ DLL

C++ side
    #include

```
extern "C"
{
    typedef void (__stdcall *PFN_MYCALLBACK)();
    int __stdcall MyUnmanagedApi(PFN_MYCALLBACK callback);
}
```

C# side

```
public delegate void MyCallback();
[DllImport("data_acquisition_sys.dll")]
public static extern void MyUnmanagedApi(MyCallback callback);

static void Main(string[] args) {

    MyUnmanagedApi(
    delegate()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Called back by unmanaged side");
    }
    );
    }
}
```

I followed the http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davidnotario/archive/2006/01/13/512436.aspx

Error

> Unhandled Exception: System.EntryPointNotFoundException: Unable to find an entry point named 'MyUnmanagedApi' in DLL 'data_acquisition_sys.dll'. at  affect_detection_sys.Program.MyUnmanagedApi(MyCallback callback) at affect_detection_sys.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\Public\Docume

Comment: There is very little evidence that you actually exported the function, no sign of __declspec(dllexport) or a mention of a .def file.  Use dumpbin.exe /exports on the DLL to see what .NET sees.  Using the anonymous method like that is also fatal, the GC will garbage collect it since it cannot see the native code using it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For all interested parties, here is a working solution to the problem.

C++ side

```
extern "C"
{
typedef void (*callback_function)();
callback_function gCBF;

__declspec(dllexport) void StartAcquisition(callback_function callback) {

    gCBF = callback;

    cout << "Acquisition started" << endl;
}

void DoWork() {
    gCBF()
}
}
```

C# side

```
[DllImport("data_acquisition_sys.dll", EntryPoint = "StartAcquisition")]
    public static extern void StartAcquisition(MyCallback callback);
StartAcquisition(delegate()
{

    Console.WriteLine("Called back by unmanaged side ");
}
);
```

Note that the callback_function is an empty method (), since returning and accepting back ANY data results in a runtime crash. This has been reported in other threads, but the answer hasn't been given.

Answer (score 1):

`MyUnmanagedApi` returns `int` and you have declared `void`. Try this:

```
public delegate void MyCallback();
[DllImport("data_acquisition_sys.dll")]
public static extern int MyUnmanagedApi(MyCallback callback);

static void Main(string[] args) {

    MyUnmanagedApi(
    delegate()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Called back by unmanaged side");
    }
    );
    }
}
```

Comment: I thought about that one too, but to no awail. The error is still there. The tutorial site I mentioned has it has MyUnmanagedApi declared void as well.